# Force acts on solenoid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-moment

> A scientist is doing an experiment with a setup consisting of 2 ideal solenoids that share the same axis. The lengths of the solenoids are both $ \ell $, the radii of the solenoids are $ r $ and $ 2 r $, and the smaller solenoid is completely inside the larger one. Suppose that the solenoids share the same (constant) current $ I $, but the inner solenoid has $ 4 N $ loops while the outer one has $ N $, and they have opposite polarities (meaning the current is clockwise in one solenoid but counterclockwise in the other).
>
> Model the Earth's magnetic field as one produced by a magnetic dipole centered in the Earth's core. Let $ F $ be the magnitude of the total magnetic force the whole setup feels due to Earth's magnetic field. Now the scientist replaces the setup with a similar one: the only differences are that the the radii of the solenoids are $ 2 r $ (inner) and $ 3 r $ (outer), the length of each solenoid is $ 7 \ell $, and the number of loops each solenoid is $ 27 N $ (inner) and $ 12 N $ (outer). The scientist now drives a constant current $ 2 I $ through the setup (the solenoids still have opposite polarities), and the whole setup feels a total force of magnitude $ F^{\prime} $ due to the Earth's magnetic field. Assuming the new setup was in the same location on Earth and had the same orientation as the old one, find $ F^{\prime} / F $.

You don't have to solve the homework, I'm having some conceptual problems.

I tend to use the formula $F=m\, \mathrm dB/\mathrm dz$, where $m$ is the magnetic dipole which the solenoid represents. So $m= ISn$, $I$ is the current flow in the solenoid, $S=r^2\pi$, $n$ is the total loop of the solenoid, then what are the length of the solenoid $s$ used for?

Comment: This question is from the Online Physics Olympiad which started yesterday... I don't think it is legal to clear your doubts on a physics site..